# True or False: $f(z)=Ln(z)$ is periodic

Tags: logarithms, periodic-functions

From [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicFunction.html):

> A function $f(x)$ is said to be periodic with period $p$ if $f(x)=f(x+np)$ for $n=1,2,3...$

The easy bait here is to realize that $Ln(z)$ is asking for the principal value of the natural logarithm (due to the capital letter L), so my guess would be that no, this is not a periodic function because the domain of the graph of $Ln(z)$ is from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Comment: At best it would be periodic as you rotate around the circle, which isn't what periodicity means in the complex numbers. $\exp$ is periodic, though.

Comment: You will need to expand on what you mean for a complex function to be periodic, Under the definition you quoted, no, $Ln$ clearly is not periodic.

Comment: @user7530 I guess there just needs to be a repeating pattern for its graph?

Comment: It's not impossible, but how are you going to graph a complex function? Not as easy as it sounds.

Comment: @barrycarter hm...i tried on Wolfram but I don't think I succeeded, nor do I now think that graphing it is the way to prove it. Any hints?

Comment: I was saying you can't easily graph a complex function because you have 2 inputs (the real and imaginary parts of z) and 2 outputs (the real and imaginary parts of Ln(z)). I'm pretty sure Ln is 1-to-1 and doesn't repeat at all, much less periodically. If Ln[z1] = Ln[z2], I believe you can show z1 = z2.

Comment: @barrycarter yea checking online confirms that $Ln$ is not periodic but the exponential function is. Still gonna try to prove it though.